# How to set a limit of items on CirclePageIndicator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using a `ViewPager` and a `CirclePageIndicator`, from `ViewPagerIndicator` lib, to show images with some circles below, but the circles are overflowing the layout, like this: [image]

There's some way to define a maximum limit of circles? To keep it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not implemented on that lib. You'll have to do it yourself by overriding the [CirclePageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java). Check the `onDraw` method to limit the number of circles drawn.

I guess that you'll also face some issues related with the selected circle indicator, but they should be easy to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The [PageIndicatorView](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView) library makes restricting the number of indicators easier. I used it instead of ViewPageIndicator, and restricted the number of indicators to the maximum that could fit on the screen with

```
  int maximumIndicators = 24;
  if (mMarkers.size() > maximumIndicators ){
      mPageIndicator.setCount(maximumIndicators);
      }
```