# CircleIndicator does not fit the screen

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using this library https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator, in some cases too much data is coming. The indicator goes out of the screen, can I add animation to it, there is an animation that exists as default in ios.

Ios Example: https://streamable.com/6nu6j3

Android Problem:

[image]

I found this as a problem like this before, i was wondering if there could be a nicer solution like in ios

[How to set a limit of items on CirclePageIndicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087569/how-to-set-a-limit-of-items-on-circlepageindicator)

Layout

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator3
    android:id="@+id/circleIndicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewPager2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:ci_drawable="@drawable/circle"
    app:ci_height="5dp"
    app:ci_width="5dp" />
```

Edit:

This library my work has been read -> https://github.com/wching/Android-Indefinite-Pager-Indicator

Comment: show your layout file

Comment: @VivekThummar I added

Comment: Is this problem occurs with only `CircleIndicator` or also with `viewpager`?

Comment: Okk, i found the problem and this will help you..https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator/issues/120

Comment: I've checked this library similar(https://github.com/zhpanvip/viewpagerindicator) to this, but I need a circle :(, I'm working myself right now.

Comment: @VivekThummar thanks , I found lib -> https://github.com/IslamKhSh/CardSlider

Answer (score 0):

you have to set margin into your root level layout according to that they set margin .....

and don't check into the emulator some time emulator may be goes wrong so check it into real device only

Comment: I check emulator and real device, result is same, I did not fully understand, can you write an example in code? root layout-> relativelayout, I tried margin there but the list feels too long, again it doesn't fit